# How to reuse an Attribute

Tags: c#

So I created a class like

```
public static class SharedDataAnnotations
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Matches letters, digits, dashes, underscores and spaces.
    /// </summary>
    public static RegularExpressionAttribute DisplayNameProperCharacters =
        new RegularExpressionAttribute(@"^[A-Za-z0-9\-_ ]+$") { ErrorMessage = "Display name can only contain letters, numbers, underscores, dashes and spaces." };
}
```

because I want to be able to reuse

```
[RegularExpression("@"^[A-Za-z0-9\-_ ]+$"", ErrorMessage = "Display name can only contain letters, numbers, underscores, dashes and spaces.")]
```

However when I try to put it on a property like

```
[SharedDataAnnotations.DisplayNameProperCharacters]
```

I get the error

> 'SharedDataAnnotations' does not contain a definition for
>   'DisplayNameProperCharacters'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't. The attribute object itself needs to be a new instance for each code element it's applied to.

You also can't refer to a non-literal value when constructing a custom attribute. So you can't pass a reference to your `DisplayNameProperCharacters` object to a custom attribute constructor.

What you *could* do is have the custom attribute take as an argument to its constructor some identifier (e.g. a string, an enum value, etc.) that specifies what behavior you actually want (e.g. look up the specific `RegexExpressionAttribute` object at the appropriate time).

Answer (score 0):

Attributes must be a typename. Depending on what libraries are doing the reading, you could decorate with an interface or base class. You could also define the regex value as a constant string for reuse.